Why get Error 2015 when dim 2d array consecutively?
When I try to define 2 2d array consecutively, I got Error 2015, this is how the code looks like:
Dim iIoTAryOnX As Variant
Dim iIoTAryOnY As Variant
Dim iIoTAryOnZ As Variant

iIoTAryOnX = [{10, 12, 13, 14, 15; 5, 7, 8, 9, 11; 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}]
iIoTAryOnY = [{11, 13; 1, 6, 9, 10, 12; 2, 8, 14; 3, 5, 7; 4, 15}]
iIoTAryOnZ = [{6, 7, 12; 4, 11, 13, 15; 1, 3, 5, 8, 14; 2, 9, 10}]

It works fine when define iIoTAryOnX, but on iIoTAryOnY, I got Error 2015.
Anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it, please help.

Deleted my previous comment now that I've spotted the [ ]. You have a #VALUE in one of those cells. Fix that or handle it with =IFERROR(... in the cell formula or IsError in the VBA

A 2D array cannot be jagged, it must have the same number of elements for all rows. You'd need a 1D array of arrays instead.

And a jagged array can be obtained using a mixed similar construction in the next way: Dim jgArray jgArray = Array([{1,2,3,4,5;15,16,17,8,30}], [{12,66,34}]). It is a 1D jagged array containing a 2D array and a 1D (1 based), too. Using Debug.Print jgArray(0)(1, 2), jgArray(1)(2) will return 2 and 66...
